# Firebase confirmPasswordReset()

Tags: firebase

Suppose that a user has 3 auth accounts linked together (email/password, gmail and facebook).  Does calling confirmPasswordReset() deletes the gmail and facebook accounts from the user Auth?  In other words, after calling confirmPasswordReset(), the user is only able to sign in with email/password.  Is that the default behaviour?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The function `confirmPasswordReset` just saves the new password for email/password authentication. To unlink the accounts, you should use this function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#unlink-an-auth-provider-from-a-user-account

Comment: In my case, the function unlink facebook, and gmail, and keeps only the email/password. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Is the user currently signed-in? If so, try using `updatePassword`

Comment: No the user is not signed in.  That is why I am calling confirmPasswordReset()

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Email-Password does not delete associated accounts.

`confirmPasswordReset (String code, String newPassword)`

> Changes the user's password to newPassword **for the account for which
> the code is valid**. Code validity can be checked with
> verifyPasswordResetCode(String). This use case is only valid for
> signed-out users, and behavior is undefined for signed-in users.
> Password changes for signed-in users should be made using
> FirebaseUser.updatePassword(String).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-taskvoid-confirmpasswordreset-string-code,-string-newpassword

Comment: In my case, the function unlink facebook, and gmail, and keeps only the email/password.  What would be the reason for that?